# Plus symbol line height

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a list with circled numbers as bullets, with the last bullet being a plus symbol to add more items. The problem is that the HTML entity for the plus symbol doesn't vertically center like the numbers do.

```
<li><span>1</span><a href="#">Item one</a></li>
<li><span>2</span><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
<li><span>+</span><a href="#">add item</a></li>
```

[image: See screenshot: [link][1]]

I'm pretty strong with CSS, but it seems strange that there isn't some way to achieve this without images, which I'm pretty close to giving up and resorting to.

Comment: The CSS for this is where?

Comment: yeah, the + sign is smaller so I've always had to fiddle with the top & bottom padding to make it similar to the numbers/letters.

Comment: Or try giving the `<span>` a class, and give it a larger font size.

Comment: As a side note.. it is more efficient to use the `:before` pseudo selector, with `content:'+';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/edisutrisno/QYymW/1) is what you're looking for?
Add this style:

```
span {
    background:#ffffff;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border:2px solid #dddddd;
    border-radius:15px;
    padding:5px 9px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: I had considered fiddling with the line-height/margin/padding, but I was hoping for a solution that would work with a variety of font-sizes and line-heights. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, the text is centered, it's just that the top of the `+` sign is filled with some empty space making it look offset.  But, if you look at the bottoms of the numbers and compare it with the `+`, they are positioned the same.

To fix this, you can either use a special case for the `+` where you actually offset its position by a few Y pixels, or you can change the font you are using to one that has the `+` positioned in the center of the area.

Comment: How to find out which font centers its plus signs?

Comment: @JustGoscha In Chrome CSS inspector (probably other also), give the element a font-family and then you can cycle through them when you clear the value and press the arrow keys. Setting line-height to 0 helps also.